# Amadeus flight search API returning 400 bad request when using the API explorer

Tags: amadeus

I'm using the Amadeus [API explorer for flight search API](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-offers-search/api-reference) to test out the service. however I seem to be getting `400 bad request` errors.

- I've tried using the default arguments of the api explorer
  https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/flight-offers?originLocationCode=SYD&destinationLocationCode=BKK&departureDate=2021-11-01&adults=1&nonStop=false&max=250
- or with my own
  https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/flight-offers?originLocationCode=TLV&destinationLocationCode=DBX&departureDate=2022-03-01&adults=1&nonStop=true&max=250

but I always get `400 bad request`. here's a screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**the first example** that you provided, the date is in the past, please try with the future date, and it should work.

Try this :
https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/flight-offers?originLocationCode=SYD&destinationLocationCode=BKK&departureDate=2022-11-01&adults=1&nonStop=false&max=250

**the second example**, DBX is not the correct city/airport code, I believe you want Dubai DXB?

Try this:
https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/flight-offers?originLocationCode=TLV&destinationLocationCode=DXB&departureDate=2022-03-01&adults=2&max=250

I recommend you to try with [Amadeus for developer Postman workplace](https://developers.amadeus.com/blog/how-to-play-with-self-service-apis-with-no-code-using-postman), you will see the details of the error message like below.

[error message from postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkVaK.png)